# Content query WP with more than two filters

Tags: content-query-web-part

We're using a content query web part (CQWP) to pull a list into a sub-site from the root site of the site collection. Is it possible to define more than two filters on a CQWP? Any reason why the CQWP has been hard-coded with a maximum of two filters only? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about 2010, and there is three filters not two btw :)

Here is a link explaining how you can override that with the QueryOverride and use of CAML:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/08/09/adding-more-than-3-filters-in-cqwp.aspx

Comment: Thanks, sorry, you're right, Anders -- it's 3 filters :)